# Cant delete pdf from desktop with long file name

Tags: pdf

I have search and tried all the basics. Nothing works. here is where I am up to.

[image]

and;

[image]

tried deleting and tried changing name from short name. i really dont know what i am doing got this far from google searches, am i doing something incorrect. your assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've had luck in cases of this nature by ensuring that the troublesome file is the only one that qualifies as PUS*.* and using del PUS*.* as the command.

If all else fails, a boot with a LiveCD running almost any version of linux will allow you to purge the problem child.

Answer (score 0):

The filename contains spaces, so they are considered as commands, you can add (*) in the place of spaces like

```
del PUSH*IN*PINTLE...pdf
```

This is a big filename. There is no other pdf file on desktop so you can try

```
del *.pdf
```

or

```
del PUSH*
```